# How can I use VLOOKUP in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: excel, vlookup, libreoffice-calc

I using Excel file to store and linking testing data (TestSets, TestCases,....). But I got problem with VLOOKUP()

I have 3 file Excel.

```
home/main/Testing/TestingFile_1.xlsx
home/main/Testing/TestingFile_2.xlsx
home/main/Testing/TestingFile_3.xlsx
```

In the TestingFile_2.xlsx, I using VLOOKUP to get a data from File1:

`=VLOOKUP("TESTING_001",'TestingFile_1.xlsx'#$TestCase.$A$6:$E$500,3,0)`

In the first time. when I pressed Enter button, the data is correct and Input line is:

`=VLOOKUP("TESTING_001",''file:///home/username/main/Testing/TestingFile_1.xlsx'#$TestCase.$A$6:$E$500,3,0)`

Then when I coppy to other location, it changed to:

`=VLOOKUP("TESTING_001",[33]testcase!$a$6:$E$500,3,0)`

Does anyone has issue it before?

Comment: So does Libreoffice file structure / links etc follow those used in Excel? Do you expect filelinks to be identical based on how functions work differently? To correct errors you need to rewrite the functions to be correct in Libreoffice and, for some functions, create a work-around as some functions just don't exist.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.